# How to get Android Application Id (not programmatically)

Tags: android, app-id

I have the app installed on my Android phone and I need to get its Application Id.

I have the example of this id in Hex format (Camera id): 226a 2a26 000a 0014 0003 0000 007f 0000 007f 0001 0003.

How can I get the same id in Hex format for any other installed application?
I don't use any code, and I'm not a Android developer, so the most preferable way is to get it not programmatically.

What is the format of Android Application Id? I only have Hex representation.

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain, in detail, where you got "the example of this id in Hex format".

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to application id, in the android system we use the "package name" .

Reference : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName%28%29

we can use the getPackageName() Method to get the details of the respective application details.